# Is it possible to get 5 V at 8 A from a battery pack?

Tags: batteries, current, battery-operated

Let me first start by saying I know very little about electric circuits, so please do pardon my ignorance.

I have a Raspberry Pi project that I want to run with a battery. Ideally it would provide two outputs with 8 to 10 A of current shared between them.

Is it possible for a lithium battery pack put out this much current? If so, what would the optimal voltage of the pack be?

I am planning on using a buck converter/voltage regulator with an input limit of 32 V. It can continuously pass 8 A, 120 W, or 12 A, 180 W with better cooling.

Comment: Lithium Ion cells can certainly output 8A and much more. You could use 2 commonly available 18650 cells in series (2S) or 2 in series and 2 in parallel (2S2P) to get 7.4V with the required output current capability, and regulate it down to 5V. It's up to you to provide the charging circuit. 2S and 2S2P packs are available pre-assembled.

Answer (score 3):

Depends entirely on a battery pack. Electric cars also have battery packs inside them and draw much more. Beefier packs can supply more current. Get an estimate on discharge current by calculating power needed + some overhead for power losses both during voltage conversion, as well as in traces/cables, since such currents will already have non-negligible losses there. Also, watch out for thermals.

So, is it possible in principle? Absolutely yes.
But you need to do some power estimations, take into account thermals, physical size & weight constraints.